# Node-SOAP Header Issue

Tags: node.js, soap, node-soap

i have a requirement to include authentication stuff on the `<soap:Header>` under a certain attribute name "RequestHeader" like `<soap:Header><RequestHeader></RequestHeader></soap:Header><soap:Body>`

but unfortunately, node-soap places this inside `<soap:Body>` instead.
so what i see is `<soap:Header></soap:Header><soap:Body><RequestHeader>`

question is, how do i move it to soap:Header? the wsdl might be at fault here but fixing it is not an option for now.

looking at the wsdl angle,
these are snippets from the wsdl, it's quite clear that the wsdl states that RequestHeaderElement should be in header, i wonder why it's being thrown to the body?

`<wsdl:input name="SendSms">
        <soap:header message="tns:SendSms" part="Headers" use="literal" />
        <soap:body parts="Parameters" use="literal" />
    </wsdl:input>`

`<wsdl:message name="SendSms">
        <wsdl:part element="ns1:RequestHeaderElement" name="Headers" />
        <wsdl:part element="tns:SendSmsRequestElement" name="Parameters" />
    </wsdl:message>`

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding a XML string literal to the header?

```
const auth = '<RequestHeader></RequestHeader>'
soap.createClient(url, soapOptions, function (err, client) {
  client.addSoapHeader(auth);
  client.myFunction(args, function (err, result) {
    console.log(client.lastRequest) //see the xml generated
  });
});
```